# What is a host address how do I get one

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I have been going through the Cardano developer tutorials and they asked me to run this code (posted below) to run a node but it responded with (Failed to parse IPv4 address: x.x.x.x.).
I figured that it's because I didn't use a valid address (line 5) how do I get one?

> cardano-node run 
> --topology path/to/mainnet-topology.json 
> --database-path path/to/db 
> --socket-path path/to/db/node.socket 
> --host-addr x.x.x.x 
> --port 3001 
> --config path/to/mainnet-config.json

Comment: Try localhost ( 127.0.0.1 ) and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You are launching a Cardano node on your server so you have to bind this node to one of your server's IP addresses.

You can try 127.0.0.1 if you want to stay local or you can go 0.0.0.0 if you want to bind the node to all the IP addresses of your server (assuming that you know what you're doing and that you've already configured the right firewall rules so you don't expose yourself).

Comment: Wait so what happens if I bind it to an invalid IP address? And maybe a follow-up, can I bind to multiple addresses? Like for example the local VPC one and the public one

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the [ip address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) to bind to. Binding to an ip address means you are creating a socket that allows flow of packets from and to that way.

You can bind to virtually any IP (even non-local one, if you permit that in the networking settings), but you'd bind to 0.0.0.0, to bind to any IP on your host, or to any of your local IP on your host, like 192.168.1.100.